# Why isn't locationManager:didUpdateLocations being called?

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, core-location, cllocationmanager

Here is some simple code:

```
// ViewControllerA.m

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.networkMonitor = [[NetworkMonitor alloc] init];

    ...

    [self.networkMonitor.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    ...
}
```

in network monitor:

```
// NetworkMonitor.m

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}

...

// this is never called!
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations 
{


    NSLog(@"%s, location manager returned a new location.", __FUNCTION__);

    ...

}

// and neither is this
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}
```

I've called startUpdatingLocation, NetworkMonitor implements CLLocationManagerDelegate...why am I not getting any calls to didUpdateLocations?  Am I misunderstanding when this method should get called? I assume that once `startUpdatingLocation` is called, I should receive at least one call to `didUpdateLocations`... I'm simply trying to get the user's current location (without using a map).  Any ideas or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you building for ios6? from docs:
In iOS 5 and earlier, the location manager calls the locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: method instead.

Comment: Brilliant!  Still building for iOS5 at the moment.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: no worries. posted as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you building for ios6? from docs: In iOS 5 and earlier, the location manager calls the locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: method instead.